# Add item to SharePoint Online list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm having a web api which is having some data in its body and that data i want to add to SharePoint online list using c#. But below code is giving me unauth error.

```cs
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    context.ExecutingWebRequest += Context_ExecutingWebRequest; // for oAuth it working in get list dat
    Web web = context.Web;  

    List topicsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
    ListItemCreationInformation newTopicInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    ListItem oListItem = topicsList.AddItem(newTopicInfo);                  

    oListItem["Title"] = "Test";
    oListItem["Column1"] = "Test1";                                    
    oListItem.Update();

    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code is working perfectly fine now, i was missing permissions to my app. For using oAuth we have to register an Add-in in SharePoint, and to post data in sharepoint i have to give FullControl to my add-in, but while creation i have made it read-only.
Below is the referance.
[Referance](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution and indeed it needs enough permission to contact with SharePoint. You could accept your own post as answer so that it could also help others in the forum.

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT please vote for the answer if it useful

Comment: already vote up, have a good day if you are concerned with this. :)

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online, use SharePointOnlinCredentials class pass credentials to authencation:

```
        string password = "*******";
        string account = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        var secret = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            secret.AppendChar(c);
        }
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"))
    {

        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        List topicsList  = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");

        ListItemCreationInformation oListItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem  = topicsList.AddItem(oListItemCreationInformation);
        oListItem ["Title"] = "New List Item";
        oListItem["Column1"] = "Test1"; 
        oListItem .Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    };
```

Comment: The above approach is marked as non secure in our tenant and i'm only allowed to use oAuth.